# Is the natural isomorphism $|FX_\bullet| \cong F|X_\bullet|$ lax symmetric monoidal?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal{V_1}$ and $\mathcal{V_2}$ be cocomplete symmetric monoidal categories, each endowed with a cosimplicial object $\Delta^\bullet=\Delta^\bullet_{\mathcal{V}_i}:\Delta \to \mathcal{V}_i$. Denote by $|-|=|-|_{\mathcal{V}_i}:s\mathcal{V}_i\to \mathcal{V}_i$ the functor tensor product $-\otimes_\Delta \Delta^\bullet_{\mathcal{V}_i}$, i.e. the coend

$$|X_\bullet|=X_\bullet \otimes_\Delta \Delta^\bullet = \int^n X_n \otimes \Delta^n$$ for $X_\bullet\in s\mathcal{V}_i$ a simplicial object in $\mathcal{V}_i$.

Let $F:\mathcal{V}_1\to \mathcal{V}_2$ be a lax symmetric monoidal functor which is a left adjoint and such that $F(\Delta^\bullet_{\mathcal{V}_1})\cong \Delta^\bullet_{\mathcal{V}_2}$.

Then there is an induced natural transformation $$\tau:|F-|\Rightarrow F|-|$$ of functors $s\mathcal{V}_1\to \mathcal{V}_2$, since $F$ preserves coends and the chosen cosimplicial objects.

Now, the category $s\mathcal{V}_i$ has a symmetric monoidal structure given by the pointwise formula $(X \otimes Y)_n = X_n \otimes Y_n$, and it is such that the induced functor $F:s\mathcal{V}_1\to s\mathcal{V}_2$ is lax symmetric monoidal. Suppose further that $|-|:s\mathcal{V}_i\to \mathcal{V}_i$ is lax symmetric monoidal. Therefore $\tau$ is a natural transformation between lax symmetric monoidal functors, so it makes sense to ask:

> Is $\tau$ a lax symmetric monoidal transformation? i.e., do the following diagrams commute?

[image]

I am under the impression that it won't be the case in general... Are there reasonable extra conditions to impose such that it will hold?

Here is an **example** of the above scenario, where I'm hoping the answer is affirmative (and it may thus serve as an inspiration to extract additional conditions to ensure a general $\tau$ above to be lax symmetric monoidal).

Consider $\mathcal{V}_1$ to be simplicial sets and $\mathcal{V}_2$ to be topological spaces. Endow the first one with the Yoneda embedding as a cosimplicial simplicial set, and endow the second one with the standard cosimplicial topological space. These objects yield internal geometric realizations: of a bisimplicial set into a simplicial set (which one can prove to be the diagonal functor), and of a simplicial space into a space (the standard one).

As a functor $F$, we will consider the standard "extrinsic" geometric realization of a simplicial set into a topological space, which satisfies all the hypotheses above. So the question in this case is whether the natural isomorphism $\tau_{X_{\bullet,\bullet}}: |\mathrm{diag} X_{\bullet,\bullet}|\cong |[n]\mapsto |X_{n,\bullet}||$ in $X_{\bullet, \bullet}\in ss\mathrm{Set}$ is (cartesian) symmetric monoidal.

Answer (score 1):

The answer might depend on how one defines the monoidal structure on the realizations $|-|:s\mathcal{V}_i\to \mathcal{V}_i$. In the topological and the simplicial cases the strong monoidal structures are determined by the preservation of products.

Observe that in both of these cases the canonical morphism $|X\times Y| \rightarrow |X|\times|Y|$ is induced through the diagonals $\Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n\times\Delta^n$ when one thinks of it as a map between the coends. One can generalize to the monoidal situation by requiring the cosimplicial object $\Delta \to \mathcal{V}$ to be a comonoid in $[\Delta, \mathcal{V}]$, so that we have $\delta_{\Delta^n} : \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^n\otimes\Delta^n$. This will define a colax monoidal structure on $|-|$

$$\int^n X_n\otimes Y_n \otimes \Delta^n \rightarrow \int^{n,m} X_n\otimes Y_m \otimes \Delta^n\otimes \Delta^m$$
$$\cong (\int^n X_n \otimes\Delta^n) \otimes (\int^m Y_m \otimes \Delta^m)$$

We also need $\otimes$ to commute with coends.

If one is given a lax monoidal functor $F$, then the composites $F|-|$ and $|F-|$ are neither lax nor colax, since $|-|$ is colax. However, one can still form the diagrams for $\tau$ by inverting in them the monoidality stucture maps for $|-|$. If $\delta_{F\Delta^n}$ equals to $\delta_{\Delta^n}$ up to the isomorphism $F(\Delta^n) \cong \Delta^n$, then these diagram will commute. The first diagram will commutive since (writing $.$ for the tensor, and omitting an index $n$)

$$FX.FY.F\Delta \rightarrow{} FX.FY.F\Delta.F\Delta \rightarrow F(X.\Delta).F(Y.\Delta) \rightarrow F(X.\Delta.Y.\Delta)$$
$$=$$
$$FX.FY.F\Delta \rightarrow F(X.Y).F\Delta \rightarrow F(X.Y.\Delta) \rightarrow F(X.\Delta.Y.\Delta),$$
which holds because of the naturality and coherence of the lax structure of $F$. The second diagram commutes because of a similar argument.

Now, if the colax monoidality morphisms are invertible, then $|-|$ will become strong monoidal, and the original diagrams in the question will commute. Hence $\tau$ will become a monoidal transformation. This is the case in the simplicial-topological example.

For the purpose of defining a lax structure on $|-|$ we could again look at our examples. In these examples the inverses of the lax structure of $|-|$ are defined as follows. In the topological case the lax monoidal structure $|X|\times|Y| \rightarrow |X\times Y|$ is constructed (-> Theorem 11.5 "The geometry of iterated loops") using certain maps

$$X_n\times X_m \times \Delta^n\times \Delta^m \rightarrow X_{n+m}\times Y_{n+m} \times \Delta^{n+m}$$

which depend on certain isomorphisms $\Delta^n\times\Delta^m \cong \Delta^{n+m}$. In the bisimplicial situation $|X|\times|Y| \rightarrow |X\times Y|$ is explicitly given via

$$(X_n\times Y_m \times \Delta^n\times \Delta^m)_r \rightarrow (X_r\times Y_r \times \Delta^r)_r$$
$$(x, y, u : r \rightarrow n, v : r \rightarrow m) \mapsto (u^\ast(x), v^\ast(y), 1 : r \rightarrow r).$$

However, these do not have straightforward generalization to the monoidal context.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! 

Sorry, but when you say "these diagrams will commute" --  could you elaborate? (also, I think there's an $m$ which should be an $n$ in your displayed coends)

Comment: Ok, added some details.

Comment: I'm confused... How do you get the morphism in your displayed coends?

Comment: The coend is defined using the natural family $1\otimes 1\otimes \delta_{\Delta^n} : X_n\otimes Y_n\otimes\Delta^n \rightarrow X_n\otimes Y_n\otimes\Delta^n\otimes \Delta^n$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, I don't see why you end up in a coend over $\Delta\times \Delta$. Shouldn't the arrow point to $\int^n X_n \otimes Y_n \otimes \Delta^n \otimes \Delta^n$?

Comment: The colimit $\int^{n,m} X_n \otimes Y_m \otimes \Delta^n \otimes \Delta^m$ still contains "summunds" $X_n\otimes Y_n\otimes \Delta^n \otimes \Delta^n$ (that is when $n = m$). So one can go to $X_n\otimes Y_n\otimes \Delta^n \otimes \Delta^n$ and still end up in the two argument coend.

Comment: Sorry I have been making some typos. I think I corrected them all now. Hope now it is clearer.

Comment: It's clearer now, thanks! $$$$ You meant "lax structure of F" rather than "colax", and in the end, you meant "depends on the structure of $\Delta^n \times \Delta^m$" (which is not $\Delta^{n+m})$). As for your last comment, I believe what's key is that $|-|:sSet\to Top$ is strong symmetric monoidal: that's where the non-trivial topology comes in. From this and a couple more properties of $|-|$, I think one can deduce formally that $|-|:sTop\to Top$ is strong symmetric monoidal. I agree with you that we cannot expect the result to hold in general without getting some control on the $|-|$'s.

Comment: Good. But, a product of the  topological n and m dimensional simplices is isomorphic to the n+m dimensional simplex.

Comment: I'm sorry, but again there is something eluding me. At the beginning you define a colax structure on $|-|$. However, you're still assuming (and using) that $F$ is *lax*, so I don't see what monoidal structure the functors $F|-|$ and $|F-|$ could have (in particular, how to make sense of a monoidal transformation between them?)

Comment: That is the point I was making. The more naturally defined structure on $|-|$ is lax. If your $F$ is lax, the compositions will not be either lax or colax. However, you can still form the diagram for $\tau$ by inverting the directions of the monoidal structure maps of $|-|$. I am talking about the commutativity of that diagram. Now, if $|-|$ is invertible, which happens to be the case in the topological and simplicial cases, then |-| is also lax and your original diagrams will commute.

Comment: In the topological and simplicial cases the inverses to the lax structure of |-| are as described in the last part of my question. However they do not have  straightforward monoidal analogues.

Comment: Above I meant "the more naturally defined structure on |-| is colax".